# Android App Development Question: How do I lower keyboard after onClick?

Tags: android, keyboard, onclick

I am writing a simple app that requires a field of input via an EditText view.  After the user hits the "sumbit" button a calculated answer appears below.  I there a way to lower the keyboard when the answer appears?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you hide the soft keyboard. Hope this helps

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mUIShowInput.getWindowToken(), 0);
```